# librdkafka: What is the use of topic.blacklist config?

Tags: apache-kafka

I didn't quiet understand the use case for having topic blacklist config. Can you give an example of when it can be used? (PS: I understand that it is used to ignore some topics in metadata information, just not sure if it is a type of filtering mechanism?) Please elaborate if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have six topics: abc, acd, bcd, test1, test2, test3. If I want to write a consumer which consumes the latter threes, I could write as follows:

> TopicFilter filter = new Blacklist("a.*,b.*");
>
> int threadNumber = xxx;
>
> streams = connector.**createMessageStreamsByFilter**(filter, threadNumber); ...

That will only consume the latter three topics, and ignore the former threes.
The reason why I could use a comma in the regular expression is because Kafka replaces it with a '|' sign to express the OR-wise logic.